# Composition of function $f (x) = \sqrt{2x^2+17}-3$ a total of $10$ times

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

[image]

So I have this question here. Obviously, I don't think I am expected to take a composition of a function 10 times. That would be crazy. My idea is that f(x) repeats 10 times and that $\sqrt{2}$ repeats 10 times too so I was thinking I could write $f(x)$ as:

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2^{(1/2)^{10}}(f(x))^{10}+17}-3.$$ I could then go from there or something. Anything to add? Am I completely off or am I doing something totally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(2)=2$ and $f(4)=4$. Moreover $f$ is a continuous and strictly increasing function in $[2,4]$. These properties hold also for the composition $g$. Therefore $g((2,4))=(2,4)$ and by  the Intermediate Value Theorem there is $c\in (2,4)$ such that $g(c)=3$.
Note that since $g$ is strictly increasing the point $c$ is unique.

Comment: Rolle's theorem?

Comment: Yes. It holds for the composition as well. So in that case, doing it 10 times means it's still 2...

Therefore, the same holds for 4.... I can then use IVT to show there is a g(c) = 3?

Comment: Ok. So use the Intermediate Value Theorem for $g$.

Comment: See my edit. Is that logic right?

Comment: @Subhashis Chakraborty Yes, it is right.